# Need to discard some OUT parameters when calling stored procedure - mybatis

Tags: stored-procedures, mybatis

I am calling a stored procedure from using mybatis ... I want to ignore some output parameters from being mapped to the Mapped object , how can I do this ?

```
  <select id="getDetails" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="map" >  
{call GET_DETAILS(
#{Null,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, --P_MSG_ID
#{header.sourceId,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=IN}, --SC_ND
. -- here I have an OUT parameter that I need to discard from the mapping
.
.
.
</select>
```

Comment: why do you want to discard it? I think you can just ignore it

Comment: then how will the code look like ?  the procedure takes the parameters byorder not by name

Comment: you can just change the output parameter name to make it do not match the map